# Reading file with C#

Tags: c#

I want to read php text file using c#. The file looks like:

```
2.20:2.20:2.20:2.20:2.20:
2012-07-12:2012-07-11:2012-07-10:2012-07-09:2012-07-08:
```

I would like to get all lines to listboxes. In real situation there is six lines, but first I should have read these two lines. My code:

```
void web_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         int i;
         string price_line = "";
         string date_line = "";
         List<decimal> prices = new List<decimal>();
         List<string> dates = new List<string>();

         using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
         {
             price_line = reader.ReadLine();
             date_line = reader.ReadLine();
             string[] bit_1 = price_line.Split(':');
             string[] bit_2 = date_line.Split(':');
             for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
             {
                 prices.Add(decimal.Parse(bit_1[i]));
                 dates.Add(bit_2[i]);
             }
             listBox1.ItemsSource = prices;
             listBox2.ItemsSource = dates;
         }
     }
     catch
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Can't read!");
     }           
}
```

Now I get "NullException". How to fix this?

Comment: in which line do you get that exception?

Comment: What is the value of `e.Error`? I'd like to guess that if there is an error then `e.Result` would be null.

Comment: I can read the first line if I comment date_line and its stuff but now I am getting NullException, if date_line is within..

Comment: Its actually NullReferenceException, but I can't see the value of error..

Comment: Did you check the runtime value of price_line?  Are you sure you are getting what you think you are asking for?

Comment: Havent checked, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

What's about:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result)) 
{
     List<string> lines = new List<string>();
     while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
         lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());

     string prices = lines.First().Split(':');

     List<decimal> listPrices = new List<decimal>();
     List<string> listDates = lines.Last().Split(':').ToList();

     foreach(string s in prices)
        listPrices.Add(double.Parse(s));

     listBox1.ItemsSource = listPrices;
     listBox2.ItemsSource = listDates;
}
```

You should check if `e.Result`, `listBox1` and `listBox2` aren't null.

Comment: Ok. But there is also another problem; I don't actually read local file but I send parameter data with web client and then php file makes SQL query and just echo data. Then I should read lines through Internet connection. That's why I have e.result..

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean, because English is not my strongest area ;) and programming even less